# Evento onChange="form.submit()" y Alert con return false

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un formulario que realiza el submit() al dar click en un checkbox mediante un onChange="this.form.submit()" pero me gustaría que lanzara un alert con return false; antes de enviar los datos a la hoja de PHP que sube los datos a MySql.

Primero fui con onClick:

```js
        <form method="POST" id="dispo" action="cambiar.php" name="dispo">

        <label class="btn btn-outline-success">

        <input name="info" type="radio" onChange="this.form.submit()" onClick="alert('¡Se van a cambiar las fechas de reserva, ¿está seguro?')return false;" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($horas['id']); ?>">

        <strong>
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($horas['horarios']); ?> <?php echo ' &nbsp;Reservar'; }?>
        </strong>
        
        </input>
        </label>
        </form>
```

Luego intenté cambiar el evento a onSubmit:

```js
        <form method="POST" id="dispo" action="cambiar.php" name="dispo" onSubmit= "alert('¡Se van a cambiar las fechas de reserva, ¿está seguro?')return false;">

        <label class="btn btn-outline-success">

        <input name="info" type="radio" onChange="this.form.submit()" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($horas['id']); ?>">

        <strong>
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($horas['horarios']); ?> <?php echo ' &nbsp;Reservar'; }?>
        </strong>
        
        </input>
        </label>
        </form>
```

Bueno gracias se que es algo fácil pero no manejo js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero realizar lo siguiente:

```js
function validarForm(sender)
{
  //obtengo mi formulario por ID
   form = document.getElementById('miformulario');
  //MUESTRO CONFIRMACION PARA HACER EL SUBMIT
  confirm = confirm('desea actualizar sus datos?');
  if(confirm == true)
  { 
    //hago el submit
    form.submit();
  }else{
    //no se realiza el submit
    alert('Los datos no han sido actualizados');
    return false;
  }
  
}//end function validarForm
```

```html
<form action="a.php" method="POST" id="miformulario">
Nombre: <br>
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"><br>
<label for="">Enviar Datos
<input type="radio" onchange="validarForm();">
</label>
</form>
```

**Explicación**

Lo primero que realizo es en tu **input** tipo **radio** en el evento **onchange** invoco a una función **validarForm** misma que mostrará un mensaje de confirmación [confirm()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) en caso de aceptar se hara el submit.

Para hacer el **submit** he obtenido el formulario mediante el **ID** .

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: perfecto, resulta excelente. le agregué un onclick="document.location.reload(true)" ya que cuando el usuario presiona queda seleccionado el radio y no permite elegir después. muchas gracias!! por si le sirve a alguien más. saludos!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que necesitas realmente es llamar a la función confirm(). Cambia el onsubmit con esto:

```
<form method="POST" id="dispo" action="cambiar.php" name="dispo" onsubmit="return confirm('¡Se van a cambiar las fechas de reserva, ¿está seguro?');">
```

Comment: gracias por responder, lo intenté pero aun sigue sin lanzar el mensaje